# Where can I get Imagenet test dataset labels for evaluation

Tags: python, pytorch, image-net

I have the imagenet train, validation and test set. I have been able to assign each image in the validation set into its respective class folders with the help of some online resources. However, for the test set, I could not find the labels.

All the model evaluation experiments on Imagenet dataset I’ve seen people do only use a fraction of the validation set. I have not been able to find one that used the test set or a fraction of it.

I really want to use the imagenet test set to evaluate my pytorch model. How do I go about it or where can I get the labels for the test set?